# How to extract file names in a loop into a character array?

Tags: matlab

I have a code like below. I want to generate an array with all the file names and combine with the data that I collected from each file.

```
  DataCC = dir('*-CC.xls'); %select the file type
  MeanAreaCC=[];
  PlateNameCC=[];
  for w = 1: numel(DataCC)
      basefilenamedata=DataCC(w).name; %extract the file name
      T=readtable(basefilenamedata); %read table in
      PlateNameCC=[PlateNameCC basefilenamedata]; %generate the file name array
      MeanAreaCC = [MeanAreaCC mean(T.Area)]; %generate the data array
  end

  x=array2table([PlateNameCC, transpose(MeanAreaCC)],'VariableNames',{'Iso-Condi-Rep','MeanAreaCC'}); %combine two arrays just generated
  writetable(x,fullfile(DataFolder,'DataSummary.xls'),'Sheet',1,'Range','A1');
```

But my code didn't work, as the `PlateNameCC` is generated as one character but not an array. This came to an error complaining different array size, when I combine `PlateNameCC` with `MeanAreaCC`. Could somebody check it for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here.

First, `PlateNameCC = [PlateNameCC basefilenamedata];` is going to create one long string of garbage.

For example:

```
fnames = dir('*.m')
namelist = [];
for ii = 1:numel(fnames)
    namelist = [namelist fnames(ii).name]
end
```

Gives me:

```
namelist =

    'SOcode.mcallbacksclass.mtestcode.m'
```

You want to use a [string array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) or a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html):

```
fnames = dir('*.m');
namelist1 = string({fnames.name});
namelist2 = {fnames.name};
```

Which returns:

```
namelist1 = 

  1×3 string array

    "SOcode.m"    "callbacksclass.m"    "testcode.m"


namelist2 =

  1×3 cell array

    {'SOcode.m'}    {'callbacksclass.m'}    {'testcode.m'}
```

Second, there's no point trying to concatenate two (very) unlike arrays to create a table when you can just use the [`table`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) constructor itself:

```
fnames = dir('*.m');
namelist = string({fnames.name});
data = [1, 2, 3];

T = table(namelist.', data.');
```

Which gives:

```
T =

  3×2 table

           Var1           Var2
    __________________    ____

    "SOcode.m"            1   
    "callbacksclass.m"    2   
    "testcode.m"          3
```

Comment: Thanks! But `namelist2 = {fnames.name};` doesn't work for me. It gives me an array with only one file name. Thats why I thinking to use loop.

Comment: Then there's only one file that matches `*-CC.xls` in your directory.

Comment: uh Sorry, my bad. i forgot the {} in the DataCC.name. It works now. Thanks!